# How do you visualize a tree in ID3 using weka?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, id3

I want to make a decision tree using weka in the format of ID3, when I do this, it is unable to be chosen. I can't select the option to view the decision tree.

Comment: To get better help you need to provide some code samples for people here to understand what you have tried.

Comment: I have no experience in the libraries you refer to but the tag for Werka states that it is a Java ML library, so I assumed you were programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize the Tree by using the JFrame in your Java Code.

```
TreeVisualizer tv = new TreeVisualizer(null, cls.graph(), new PlaceNode2());
JFrame jf = new JFrame("Weka Classifier Tree Visualizer: J48");
 jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 jf.setSize(800, 600);
 jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 jf.getContentPane().add(tv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 jf.setVisible(true);

// adjust tree
tv.fitToScreen();
```

You can find the more help

[weka Sample Code for Visualization](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/wekaexamples/src/main/java/wekaexamples/gui/)

Please share your code for more help. Thanks